# ERR_ACCESS_DENIED in webView in android with test device Android Pie

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I am trying to loadURL() in my webview and getting the following error
ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

PS: I have given the required permission in Android_Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please suggest

Android_Manisfest.xml file content -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pgm5">
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the URL?

Comment: I am trying as a demonstration, so the URL is "http://rcub.ac.in/english/"

Comment: are you trying to load it with HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: http.

 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://rcub.ac.in");

Comment: try loading myWebView.loadUrl("http://rcub.ac.in/");

Comment: I tried this but same error myWebView.loadUrl("http://rcub.ac.in/");

Comment: try loading `myWebView.loadUrl("http://rcub.ac.in/");`

Comment: I had included http in my previous comment as well but it was removed somehow

Comment: Yes, the same I am trying. It has http prefix to it. I have mailed you screenshot of my error as well.

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` 
file

Comment: I have edited the question with my AndroidManifest.xml content

Comment: I've posted an answer

Comment: I checked with the edited file, I continue to get the same error

Comment: Try uninstall and reinstall the app

Comment: Tried reinstalling but still same error :-(

Comment: Add this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Also, try to load it on a Real device

Comment: @RahulKhurana still same error, even after insertion of network state

Comment: Can you ask the website owner to install SSL so the address should begins with HTTPS?

Comment: I tried with both unsecured(http) and secured(https) still the same error.

Comment: I just tried your URL on a real device and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Check now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pgm5">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```